# Applying for a second Singapore Tourist Visa within a short period

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, singapore, tourist-visas

I'm an India national. I visited Singapore with a tourist visa and stayed there for one month (from Apr 23 - May 22nd). I want to visit Singapore again for 18 days in the month of July as tourist. If I apply for a tourist Visa within 45 days of my return from Singapore, will I get approval for my visa or is there any chances to get rejected?

Answer (score 2):

**You should be fine.** Tourist visas get rejected if they think you are working illegally in Singapore, but if there's a gap of several months since your last visit and you only want to stay for 18 days, this should not be a problem.

Standard disclaimer: Nobody here has inside info, the only way to get a definitive answer is to apply and find out.